# Error Message : TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

[In form validation in react js , it is getting error why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uufm.png)

this is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP8jt.png)

Comment: I am guessing the way you calling this function is wrong so you have lost the reference of `this` keyword. Can you share the code where you are calling the function `handleUserInput` ?

Comment: @swojanya thanks for joining stackoverflow. This question requires a bit of editing to be useful for the future. I would recommend to actually transcript the issue and put it as code bocks and be specific with the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` in your methods. By convention, this is done in the constructor.

Examples can be found [here](https://dev.to/abodmicheal/3-methods-of-binding-in-react-2fid).